# Find Line through the origin which minimizes the squared perpendicular distances to given points

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry

Given a set of Points $p_i\in \Re^d$, I'm looking for the vector $x\in\Re^d$ with $\| x \|=1$ along a line so that minimizes $$\sum_{i}(\|p_i\|^2 - \langle p_i, x\rangle^2)$$
According to the first part of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201951/find-a-line-such-that-sum-of-perpendicular-distances-of-points-to-the-line-is-mi) the right singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value can be used to do this however I have trouble proving that.
I can prove that it minimizes $$\sum_{i}(\|p_i\|^2 - \langle p_i, x\rangle)$$ So without the squared scalar product since it can be written as $\langle p_i, x\rangle=p_i^Tx$.
$\sum_{i}(p_i^Tx)$ can be written as $\|Ax\|_2^2$ where $A$ contains $p_i^T$ in every row.
And $\|Ax\|_2^2$ is maximized by using the Singular Value decomposition of $A$.
I'm just not sure if it also holds true for the original case
$\sum_{i}(\|p_i\|^2 - \langle p_i, x\rangle^2)$

Comment: isn't it easier to talk about maximizing $\sum_i \langle p_i,x\rangle^2$ subject to $\| x\|=1$ ? anyway I think it is not an NP-hard problem.

Comment: You are maximizing a quadratic form on the unit sphere, this is known as trust region problem.

Comment: sorry, this question is probably better suited for math.stackexchange since I'm not a professional.
Also as @DimaPasechnik wrote, this problem is the same as maximizing $x^TAx$ subject to $\|x\|=1$ where $A=\sum_{i}(p_ip_i^T)$ if I'm not completely wrong.